# SharePoint Online upload solutions programmatically

Tags: c#, javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online (365) I want to add solutions (.wsp) to the "Web Designer Galleries" (_catalogs/solutions/Forms/). I saw a post that said it is possible, but I haven't seen anything showing how. I would also like to activate these solutions as well, which that same post said is not possible. I am looking for any way to do this: JavaScript, REST, C#, PowerShell, whatever. I've been looking into this for a while and so far no dice. I'm really hoping I'm missing something here.

As the title states: I need to be able to do this programmatically. I need to be able to upload multiple solutions to the gallery at one time, or automated at least.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question answered on sharepoint.stackexchange.com, see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90809/is-it-possible-to-activate-a-solution-using-client-code-in-sharepoint-online-201

You can use CSOM to upload a wsp file to a list, there are a few ways of doing this, depends on where you're wsp files are to be loaded from as well.